# How do transmission-cli clients punch through NAT?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

Trying to figure out how to configure nftables on self-hosted tracker (running [bittorrent-tracker](https://github.com/webtorrent/bittorrent-tracker)) and transmission-cli clients.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Do you mean which inbound ports does it use?

Comment: @PhilipCouling I am trying to self-host my own tracker and seed torrent from a Linux transmission-daemon client (over Mullvad with port forwarding configured) to a macOS Transmission client (over Mullvad). macOS client sees tracker and gets peer (a single seeder, me). Unfortunately, story ends there… no download is initiated. I can’t figure out why.

Comment: In "real world" torrents there are some seeds who have set up port forwarding through their NAT router.  Bittorrent is intelligent enough to figure out which have and have not. When one client tries to use another as a seed at least one must have setup this port forwarding.  If neither have then they will not be able to communicate with each other.  I guess what you are asking then is how to setup port forwarding for transmission (cli).

Comment: In theory, port forwarding was configured on the server that seed file (the one running transmission-cli). Not sure why macOS client cannot download file from it.